# How to find the maximum value in JSON array which also contains some JSON array

Tags: javascript, jquery

Please find the below array JSON Object.

```
points:[{x:1, YValues:[34,45,56]}, {x:5, YValues:[20,12,30]}, {x:8, YValues:[12,13]}]
```

I want to find the maximum value of `X` and find the maximum value of `YValues` separately.

I don't expect for loop to find the maximum value. Expecting in simple way to find the maximum of `X` as well as maximum of `YValues` from `points` JSON object.

Is it possible to use `Math.max` or any custom function ?

Thanks,
Siva

Comment: what you have tried ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this?

```
Math.max.apply(0,points.map(function(v){return v.x}));
```

Still a loop, but it's succinct.

Here's how to do it for `YValues`. A long line though:

```
Math.max.apply(0,[].concat.apply([],arr.map(function(v){return v.YValues})));
```

Comment: whether it will return only maximum of X. how can i find maximum of YValues

Comment: See my edit. It becomes a bit unreadable tho, you might want to create separate variables or a little function.

Comment: thanks but i want only maximum of YValues[1] and X ? not whole YValues array.select all YValues[1] and find maximum and minmum as well

Comment: Math.max.apply(0,points.map(function(v){return v.x})); -> it returns Nan

Comment: sorry elclanrs. working fine. excellent solution. thank you very much

Comment: I wouldn't let such code pass if I were reviewing it. It's clever but unmaintainable.

Comment: @FlorianMargaine: First one is fine, I don't see the problem there. The second one I would just abstract the flatten function and apply it inline with the map.

Comment: The 1st would be fine with some newlines. The second would definitely need to be split up.

Comment: First one is basically a quick lambda, reads better in one line TBH.

Answer (score 1):

I made soultion using javascript 1.8 Array `reduce` method . Please note it works only in modern browsers

```
var max = yourObj.points.reduce( function ( a, b ){
    a.x = Math.max.apply( 0, [a.x,b.x] ) ;
    a.y = Math.max.apply( 0, [].concat( [ a.y ], b.YValues ) )
    return a;
}, { x :0, y :0 } );
```

the `max` variable contains maximum x and y

```
console.log( max.x );
console.log( max.y );
```